# SSRS Filter with a different column from a different dataset

Tags: reporting-services, filter, iif

I want to filter my column, let's call it AllStudentID from dataset1 with another column from a different datset.

Dataset1 had many column such as AllStudentID, Class, Time, Location.
Dataset2 has other columns but i'm focused on a similar column called OnCampusID.

I've tried looking into using a filter but since the report itself has the columns from Dataset1, i run into an issue where if I select the column in dataset2, it always gives a First(OnCampusID). And I don't want that.

I looked into IIF() but again, i'm using a column from a different datset plus if let's say that they are NOT equal, I don't want to display anything, instead of putting something there. I know that you have to put a result if true and a result if false. 
If I"m thinking of it in terms of SQL statements, it's like having a WHERE clause WHERE AllStudentID=OnCampusID.

I tried running a Parameter but I don't want the select part on the top but rather have the report filtered already.

Am I missing something? I know it has to be simple.

Mind you, the following example above is just an example i made up, not the real thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that each OnCampusID only appears once in Dataset2 then you can do a [Lookup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee210531.aspx) expression to filter it:

```
=IIF(IsNothing(Lookup(Fields!AllStudentID.Value, Fields!OnCampusID.Value, Fields!OnCampusID.Value, "Dataset2")), False, True)
```

If OnCampusID appears more than once in Dataset2 then do the same thing using [LookupSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee240819.aspx).

To get the graduate field from Dataset2 just to a `Lookup` in the `Value` of the cell, like so:

```
=Lookup(Fields!AllStudentID.Value, Fields!OnCampusID.Value, Fields!Graduate.Value, "Dataset2")
```

Comment: Each record on ONCampusID should only appear once in the dataset2 and they also should only appear once in the entire column of AllStudent ID.

Case in point: ALlStudentID has 10,11,12,13,14,15
OnCampusID has 10,13,15

The result of the report should only spit out 10,13,15.

Comment: Continuing on the example

Dataset1 has column ALlStudentID which has 10,11,12,13,14,15. Dataset1 also has column Graduate which has Y,N,N,Y,N,Y respectivly with each record in allStudentId.
Dataset2 has column OnCampusID which has 10,13,15

The result of the report should only spit out 10,13,15 and Y,N,Y respectively

Comment: The first part of the answer does the filter as per your first comment. I have added the lookup for the graduate field to the answer.